# Pass a global array to routine for altering using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have various classes, and am trying to make routines that can edit global arrays for the respective classes. Let me explain..

Let's say one class is a person. Contained in this class is NAME, SSN, DOB, ADDRESS(as an object), etc.

Another class would be address. Contained in this class is NUMBER, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIPCODE.

I have global arrays which hold each object for those classes. So I have an array of people and an array of addresses.

```
 Public Shared peopleArr() as peopleClass
 public shared addressArr() as addressClass
```

I am writing a method to resize the arrays as objects are added. So if a person is added the routine will check to see whether or not the array is empty and will subsequently add an empty spot creating a new object.

```
 redim preserve peopleArr(0 to 1)
 peopleArr(1) = new personClass
```

I would like one routine to complete this task no matter what type of array is being altered, but I keep getting an error "Option Strict On disallows narrowing from type 'Object()' to type 'PersonClass()' in copying the value 'ByRef' parameter 'objectArray' back to the matching argument.

If I turn off option strict then I get an error at runtime:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'SMv3._0.personClass[]'.'

Basically, whether personArr or addressArr is passed, I'd like the routine to resize it and create a new item of the respective class, and actually make that change to the global array.

Here is the main call:
CreateRemoveObjectArraySpot(globalVariables.personArr(), "")

and here the the routine:

```
 Public Sub CreateRemoveObjectArraySpot(ByRef objectArray As Object(), deleteString As String)
    Try
        If deleteString = "" Then 'if deletestring is "" then an array spot will be created
            If objectArray Is Nothing Then
                ReDim objectArray(0 To 0)
                objectArray(0) = New Object
            Else

            End If
        Else 'if deletestring is not blank then the array spot containing the string will be deleted

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorDisplay(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: If these are global arrays, why do you need to pass them at all?  Can you show us the class definitions. And why use Arrays at all? collection types are much easier to deal with saving all the hassle of resizing arrays in the first place

Comment: I am not sure, I am not a professional coder, I do it part time for my agency. I don't know how else to store objects other than in an array. I will research collection types, thanks for the input

Comment: As suggested, you should be using collections rather than arrays if you want to be able to add and remove items. The generic `List(Of T)` provides "dynamic array" behaviour, where you can access items by index but also add and remove at will. You specify the type `T` so it can store whatever type you like. In your case, use `Public Shared people As New List(Of peopleClass)` and the like.

Comment: Also as suggested, the whole point of using global variables is so that you don't have to pass them around so using and then passing them around is defeating the whole point. You probably should not be using global variables in the first place and you should be passing them around but that's going to be a bigger change. If you already have global variables then use them properly, i.e. just refer to them directly wherever you need to. the only reason to pass them as an argument is if you might need to pass other arrays to the same method(s) at other times.

Comment: That is why I was passing them, because I wanted the same method to perform changes to different arrays, but I was unaware of the list and collection types. I appreciate the comments and advice. How do I close out this question without simply deleting it (or would you recommend deleting it)?

Comment: I am updating my code and I am running into the same problem. I am using a routine to populate a listbox with the items in a list, and depending on which list is relevant, passing it to the routine, however, I am running into the same issue as I did with the array? I can add a very simple for each loop in each control event, but I'd still like to know how to make it work the way I want, if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a very different question to what you've asked here.  Perhaps a new question with your class definitions might be in order

Comment: I guess it is a different question now, but I think I may have figured out the answer. The change I made now works with the lists but not sure it would work with arrays also. Basically, when passing the parameter to the routine, I was using "objectList(of Object)" but I switched it to "objectList(of VariantType)" and it seems to work the way I was hoping. I need to finish some of the routines to be sure. Thank you everyone for your comments.